# jQuery form serialize - empty string

Tags: jquery, html

My html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $("#bt1").click(function() {

            var f = $("#form1");
            var formData = f.serialize();

            alert(formData);
        });

    }); 
</script> 

 <div id="div1">
      <form id="form1" action="/Home/Test1" method="post" name="down">
        <div id="div2">
            <input id="input1" type="text" value="2" />
        </div>    
      </form>
  </div>

 <input type="submit" id="bt1" />
```

When I fire up the click event, formData is empty. I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You have to give the `input` element a name. E.g.:

```
<form id="form1" action="/Home/Test1" method="post" name="down">
    <div id="div2">
        <input id="input1" type="text" value="2" name="foo"/>
    </div>    
</form>
```

will give you in the alert box `foo=2`.

`.serialize()` takes the name and the value of the form fields and creates a string like `name1=value1&name2=value2`. Without a name it cannot create such a string.

Note that `name` is something different than `id`. Your form also would have not worked if you used it in the "normal" way. **Every form field needs a name.**

Comment: are ids necessary for form serialize btw?

Comment: Let me suggest to include Madbreaks's answer here too.

Comment: I have a name but I still have the empty string when serializing my view is a collection so the names are for instance [0].Unit, [0].Currency

Comment: Answer below helped me... make sure your inputs are not DISABLED!

Comment: ...and I had two form tags nested...was trying to serialize the inner form and got an empty string!. Never have nested HTML form tags.

Answer (score 86):

Although it doesn't apply to this particular example, the same behavior occurs if one or more form inputs is `disabled`.  Those inputs will not show up in the serialized string.  In my case, all form inputs had values but were disabled, resulting in an empty string being returned.

Comment: That's a nasty one. Wanted to disable the fields while I'm sending the mail ajax-style and did it _before_ serializing the form...

Comment: Oh my gosh this was an issue that was driving me crazy. +1 man, any way to make it work on disabled elements?

Comment: @Noitidart You could write your own `serialize` jQuery extension that iterates over the inputs and includes disabled ones.  But there's no way to do it, as far as I know, using out-of-the-box jQuery.

Comment: It makes sense not to include disabled elements, since disabled elements should not contain user input.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Sure, but not containing user input does not mean "does not have a value".

Comment: This just happened to us. In our case we disabled only the submit button after it was clicked. For Firefox that was enough, and it sent all of the form values as empty. Chrome, incidentally, sent the data fine. Daniel Lang's comment above was the answer. I serialized first, and then disabled the button before the actual POST.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `name`attribute in the input... that may be a problem for serialize.

```
<input id="input1" type="text" value="2" name="input1" />
```

Comment: Man. You are such a life saviour !! Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure there are no 2 elements with the same id on the page.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use comments in future. Thanks :)